# Dotnet build crashes with Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core

As I run the default from VS2017 generated Dockerfile, after a few minutes I get the following error:

> The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet build "XXX.csproj" -c Release -o /app' returned a non-zero code: 4294967295: failed to shutdown container: container e9402aaef7780a5c66dca0e3b9f5683c3c2cc079ff7934844301067bd1ce07ad encountered an error during Shutdown: failure in a Windows system call: The connection with the Virtual Machine hosting the container was closed. (0xc037010a)

As I am new with Docker, I have no idee. Does anybody know, why or how can I solve it?

I am using Docker 19.03.4.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["XXX.csproj", "XXX/"]
.
.
.
COPY ["XXX.csproj", "XXX/"]
RUN dotnet restore "XXX.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/XXX"
RUN dotnet build "XXX.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "XXX.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", XXX.dll"]
```

---

UPDATE:
I removed all of the images (48), now works, just takes a looooooong time.

Comment: First of all it's better to avoid problem details in German :))) Fortunately I could understand what is says :) 1. Are you using docker for windows? 2. Looks like your virtual linux machine where docker runs shut's down by some reason. Are you using hyper-v (default VM provider for docker for windows)?

Comment: Yes I know, sorry: "The connection with the host is closed"

Comment: I've just added a few qustions above, could you provide those info pls

Comment: 1. Yes, Windows 2. Hyper-V: yes

Comment: Are there any customization in build process for this project? Does this build relies on some docker commands? E.g. run some containers during build, some post-actions etc?

Comment: @n.piskunov: No, a simple asp.net core project with some sub-projects.

Comment: Error output is generated from docker build command? Are you runing it via cmd/ps or using launch from VS user interface?

Comment: Did you try this ? https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2821 Looks like it could be caused by base image version

Answer (score 0):

Looks like dotnet build is failing, it is better to build and publish binaries outside and just copy them to docker image and it reduces docker build time.

Comment: I think the whole idea of Dockerfiles are to allow you to build (and if neccesary compile) dependencies/applications needed in the image. dotnet build should work just fine.

Comment: It should be changed as a comment, as you are not answering the actual question.

Comment: New Docker layers are created for every ADD, RUN and COPY command, what is the point in copying source file and compiling it, where you can just copy compiled project and it reduces image size and docker build time.

Comment: @MrFox It (almost) gets you reproducible builds! Why limit docker for reproducible deployments only when you can (almost) get reproducible builds for free as well? As for layer size, you can reduce the number of RUN commands and delete files you know you are not going to use in the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of .net core container image

insert a little run command as shown below

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet --version
COPY ["XXX.csproj", "XXX/"]
```

also check the dotnet version of your local machine

```
dotnet --version
```

The two versions should match. I've ran into issues in the past where one was a preview version.